# How can I separate pages in this tape-bound booklet?

Tags: books

1. My grandparents fancy posting to walls some pictures in this Travel Alberta catalogue, rather than paying for pictures (to be printed). But they can't cut out pages as the pictures are printed without borders on some pages; cutting out pages would cut out the picture too.
2. Am I correct that this is denominated [tape binding](https://advocateprinting.net/booklet-binding-101-which-method-is-best-for-your-project/)?

[image]

Comment: Why can't they cut the pages? I didn't understand your logic on this part. If you mean some of the pictures spread across two pages, and you don't want to lose the part of the picture in the middle, you might find that forcibly opening the book at that point, breaking the spine will allow you to cut the page out. Please expand your question showing some examples of pictures they might want to extract from the book?

Comment: @CaiusJard Each page extends all the way to the spine. They can't cut along the the spine, only a few centimeters away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are going to cut-up the pamphlet and remove pages, there's no need to preserve the pamphlet.

The best way to remove pages from a glued binding is to

1. 'Break' open the binding at the page you want to remove and flatten the book on a table top. Don't heat the glue as this will liquify the glue which will create a mess. Better to cool the pamphlet so the glue is brittle.
2. Turn the book facing up.
3. Inspect the "reader's spread" (That's what an illustration that crosses two adjoining pages of a book is called.) If you are lucky there will be a thin white inside margin space between rough edge of the pages and the photograph.

*Decision time*: Before you do remove the page, If the edges of the photograph appear to not match if you trim off the margin, you may wish to stop at this point. You can still preserve the pamphlet by closing the booklet and heating the binding glue to re-seal the pamphlet.

4. If there is a white margin, pull the desired pages from the booklet. Doing this carefully, will let you pull the page as if it was a sheet in a "memo-pad" without tearing it. The inside edge of the removed page will be ragged and may have a bit of glue that you can remove with your fingers.
5. carefully trim the edge from one page of the pamphlet. You will use this to overlay on the page that still has an edge margin. Trim just enough from the bottom page to remove rough edge that might remain from where you pulled the page free from the broken spine
6. Use glue or double-sided tape to attach the upper page onto the bottom of the assembly making sure to align the edges as best you can.
   If done carefully, You will be able to place the "double-trucked" (another term for abutted pages that make up an illustration that crosses the "gutter" of the pamphlet.

Usually, these kinds of pages are printed "bleeding edge" which means printed right to the edge of the page with no margins.

7. You can either matte the print assembly (in a hole cut slightly smaller than the picture from a decorative paper to frame the print) or just centre the page on an attractive background and frame the picture for your grandparents.

I think that's a very nice thing to do.

Good Luck, and have fun.

Comment: Many thanks! "crafts.graphicdesign.com": Is this link correct?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal  Updated - correction: You might want to ask this question at https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com where I and others who do this stuff everyday hang out. Other opinions about the best way to do this might also be suggested at https://crafts.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more likely to be perfect binding than tape binding, but the two techniques are similar. It's often a heat-softening glue that is used to bind the pages, so you may find that heating the spine to a reasonably high temperature (with a hair dryer or similar) will soften the glue and allow pages to be pulled out. You may find, as per my comment, that forcing the book open and flat against the table at the page you want will break the spine/fold the glue and allow full view of the page to be extracted. Pictures that span two pages and run across the spine are unlikely to be printed right the way up to the page edge, so some careful use of an craft knife (a knife with a thin razor edge blade that is pre-scored into sections and can be progressively snapped to create a new sharp point) and a metal ruler will extract the pictures you want

Perhaps also, consider that the internet will be stuffed full of pictures that are vistas and scenes from Alberta, both professional and amateur, with and without royalty or licensing. Named places and known tourist spots/events should be easy to search for and ideally would be detailed or referenced in this catalog, so finding a digital high quality version of favored pictures, that you can have professionally printed up onto canvas etc as a gift, might make for a better overall result.

Comment: Thanks. Your last para.: They're trying to avoid paying for pictures (to be printed).

Comment: If you bought(or maybe you know someone with a big printer) them one (as a gift) then they wouldn't be paying for it, and it could work well as a birthday or anniversary item- I know I always struggle for gifts ideas for my grand parents because they seem to already have everything they want and here is only so many times I can hug the same bottle of whisky before it starts to look like I put no thought into it!

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal Before you download and print (copy) an image found on the Internet, you might want to investigate the existing Copyright laws in effect where you are. This violates Canadian copyright laws for example. Just because you can, does not mean you should.

Comment: @Stan hence the *"with and without royalty or licensing"* wording - I make the basic assumption that people are generally good, and will seek to properly license a licensable image for the use to which they intend to put it..

Comment: Royalty and or licensing is completely unrelated to Copyright law. Big difference. Your comment suggests a widely held misunderstanding of this. In addition, since you mention Alberta, Canadian copyright law exists automatically with the creator of the content unless specifically and legally 'assigned' to another entity. Canadian copyright law has been recently made much more stringent than a few years ago. Students here may not even photocopy a page from a textbook. Do check with a legal professional regarding your assumptions regarding this. Please edit your answer to reflect this reality.